# run batch file using Tauri ( using Javascript) in Windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, shell, tauri

I'm using Tauri with React JS as frontend in **WINDOWS**.

> And this App i'm trying to make is also for windows for now

I want to write a **batch script inside user's computer** then run it .

I'm making a small app which will set user's desktop wallpaper, as I came across electron then searched its alternative and choose tauri - https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/

I came to a conclusion on how to make it -

1. first save the image that is clicked inside user's directory **which i achieved** .
2. second was to write a batch file inside the user's directory to change the wallpaper which i half achieved as I wrote the file to selected destination but - the content of batch file is -

```
@echo off
set "wallpaperPath=C:\Users\<me>\OneDrive\Desktop\image.jpg"
reg add "HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%wallpaperPath%" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

in react is wrote like this using escape sequence  -

```
const scriptContent = `@echo off\nset "wallpaperPath=C:\\Users\\<me>\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\image.jpg"\nreg add "HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%wallpaperPath%" /f\nRUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters`;
```

but the problem is it is writing the file content like this as it returns UTF8 format (this is the saved file content from user's directory)-

```
@echo off
set "wallpaperPath=C:UsersmeOneDriveDesktopimage.jpg"
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%wallpaperPath%" /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

> here there is no **slashes** used

3. The last one and **Main** **problem** is that how will I **run** this file as these will be depend on each other like - first image will be saved , soon after file will be written , then just after that the file will be executed.

I watched all the documents and api guides , i went through the discussion channel to find out what others had problem while using shell but in the end I'm confused on how will this work .
Link to shell api - https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/shell

I tried everything I could think of, I have been working on this this small project from 5-6 days , I know this can be achieved by using other Languages but now It's a challenge to me as i spent a lot of time on this .

Once again -

1. how to write file in other format to save it as i liked , as it's necessary to run.
2. how can i run this file automatically after that.

> **IMPORTANT** - any other approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, u can for sure use the sidebar thing,
Though i guess this can be done directly using rust code too

Full reference with sidecars: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/sidecar/

***Extract from the docs***

Tauri.Conf.json

```json
{
  "tauri": {
    "bundle": {
      "externalBin": [
        "/absolute/path/to/sidecar",
        "relative/path/to/binary",
        "binaries/my-sidecar"
      ]
    },
    "allowlist": {
      "shell": {
        "sidecar": true,
        "scope": [
          { "name": "/absolute/path/to/sidecar", "sidecar": true },
          { "name": "relative/path/to/binary", "sidecar": true },
          { "name": "binaries/my-sidecar", "sidecar": true }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A binary with the same name and a -$TARGET_TRIPLE suffix must exist on the specified path. For instance, "externalBin": ["binaries/my-sidecar"] requires a src-tauri/binaries/my-sidecar-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu executable on Linux. You can find the current platform's target triple by looking at the host: property reported by the rustc -Vv command.

If the grep and cut commands are available, as they should on most Unix systems, you can extract the target triple directly with the following command:

```bash
rustc -Vv | grep host | cut -f2 -d' '
```

On Windows you can use PowerShell instead:

```bash
rustc -Vv | Select-String "host:" | ForEach-Object {$_.Line.split(" ")[1]}
```

JS / TS

````js
import { Command } from '@tauri-apps/api/shell'
// alternatively, use `window.__TAURI__.shell.Command`
// `binaries/my-sidecar` is the EXACT value specified on `tauri.conf.json > tauri > bundle > externalBin`
const command = Command.sidecar('binaries/my-sidecar')
const output = await command.execute()```
````

Comment: so the sum up will be , - create a folder named 'binaries' inside the 'src-tauri' folder, then place my JS file there , write the path and scope in config file ,then write the code to execute it. ??

Comment: **batch file not js

Comment: exe file not batch file